# Define a function named food which receives two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Its suppose to print:

```
no food
breakfast,marmalade
breakfast,coffee
lunch,dessert
dinner
no food
no food
dinner,dessert
```

```py
 def food(input,boolean):
    time = int(input)
    food_type = ""
    if time >= 0 and time < 6 or time >= 22:
        food_type = "no food"
    if time >= 6 and time <= 10:
        food_type = "breakfast"
    if time >= 11 and time <= 15:
        food_type = "lunch"
    if time >= 16 and time < 22:
        food_type = "dinner"
    dessert = ""
    if boolean == True and food_type == "breakfast":
        dessert = "marmalade"
    if boolean == False and food_type == "breakfast":
        dessert = "coffee"
    if boolean == True and food_type == "lunch":
        dessert = "dessert"
    if boolean == True and food_type == "dinner":
        dessert = "dessert"
    return ','.join((food_type, dessert))
```

Basically right now, I have a comma between return '' so it will print `breakfast, marmalade` but then when it comes to `no food` it adds a comma in the end, so it looks like `no food,`

Its suppose to look like:

```
no food
breakfast,marmalade
breakfast,coffee
lunch,dessert
dinner
no food
no food
dinner,dessert
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain the about the output you want, but I think you want to not have the `dessert` or the comma if the `food_type` would be `"no food"`, even if the `boolean` is `True`. I can think of at least two different ways to do that.

The first way is to replace

```
    food_type = "no food"
```

with

```
    return "no food"
```

Another way would be to replace

```
  return ','.join((food_type, dessert))
```

with

```
  output = food_type
  if output != "no food":
    output = ','.join((food_type, dessert))
  return output
```

Some people would prefer the second one since there is only one `return`.

Comment: Thank you. Now an additional issue popped up. A new comma got added to dinner, so it became dinner, Besides this, all good.

Comment: Ah. The comma is being added with the `join` when the `dessert` variable is still `""`. `','.join(("dinner", "")) == "dinner,"`. You could add another `if` to avoid that case. Or if you went with the `if output != "no food":` version you could do `if output != "no food" and dessert != "":` instead.

Comment: You are a saviour. Thank you and I really appreciate your help.